# rpmbuild perl package - rpminfo return nothing

Tags: rpmbuild

built a perl-DirTree rpm package to simulate tree package for testing, purely perl code. Everything went well except rpminfo return nothing

what did I do wrong?

or it is just rpminfo does not support perl rpm?

what else information should I provide? Thanks

```
# return everything needed
rpm -qi perl-DirTree

[gliang@www ~]$ rpm -ql perl-DirTree
/usr/share/doc/perl-DirTree-0.01
/usr/share/doc/perl-DirTree-0.01/Changes
/usr/share/doc/perl-DirTree-0.01/README
/usr/share/man/man3/DirFormat.3pm.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/DirTree.3pm.gz
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/DirFormat.pm
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/DirTree.pl
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/DirTree.pm

# my own package(installed) - return nothing
rpminfo perl-DirTree

# installed one from yum, same thing, return nothing
rpminfo perl-File-BaseDir
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rpminfo is never meant for perl
most for c/c++ etc
There is nothing wrong with my rpmbuild
Here is the code block

```
READELF=/usr/bin/readelf
EU_READELF=/usr/bin/eu-readelf
OBJDUMP=/usr/bin/objdump
TMPDIR=/tmp

progname=`basename $0`
```